# Problem in yfinance for ticker starting with ^

Tags: python, yfinance

When I am using a single ticker, everything works fine:

`my_ticker = yf.Ticker("^IXIC")`

`my_ticker.history(period='max')`

However, when I am using a list of tickers, I encounter an issue.
`my_tickers = yf.Tickers("TMUS SPOK ^IXIC")`
Priting my_tickers successfully return <TMUS,SPOK,^IXIC>
But  `my_tickers.history(period='max')`  fails with  `AttributError: 'Tickers' object has no attribute '^IXIC'`

I believe the issue might be due to the ^, as  `my_tickers.history(period='max')`  works fine when my list of tickers contains another stock instead of the index ^IXIC.

`print(my_tickers.tickers.^IXIC.history)`  returns a Syntax error whilst it works with the other two stocks.

Can someone advise?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you post the declaration of `my_tickers` list?

Comment: I tried to get the three stocks you mentioned in your question, but could not get them with the error you pointed out. I don't know the cause, but in this case, you should make a list of stocks and combine them in a loop process.

Comment: I modified the way I declare the tickers, with the same results: my_tickers = yf.Tickers("TMUS SPOK ^IXIC")

Comment: For example, you can create a `ticker_list=['TMUS','SPOK','^IXIC']` and loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, we make a list of stocks we want to get and add them to an empty dataframe that reads them sequentially. I used `yf.download()` to handle this, but the same is true for `yf.history()`.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

ticker_list = ["TMUS", "SPOK", "^IXIC"]

data = pd.DataFrame()
for ticker in ticker_list:
    tmp = yf.download(ticker, start="2021-01-01", end="2021-03-01")
    tmp['ticker'] = ticker
    data = pd.concat([data, tmp], axis=0)

data
    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume  ticker
Date                            
2020-12-31  133.149994  135.000000  133.100006  134.850006  134.850006  2080600     TMUS
2021-01-04  134.300003  134.979996  130.460007  132.429993  132.429993  3433100     TMUS
2021-01-05  131.949997  132.240005  130.460007  131.850006  131.850006  2544200     TMUS
2021-01-06  130.720001  131.979996  129.610001  131.529999  131.529999  4486000     TMUS
2021-01-07  133.809998  135.449997  133.160004  133.190002  133.190002  4928100     TMUS
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-02-22  13714.200195    13757.059570    13530.959961    13533.049805    13533.049805    6435100000  ^IXIC
2021-02-23  13262.610352    13526.089844    13003.980469    13465.200195    13465.200195    7482840000  ^IXIC
2021-02-24  13400.250000    13607.360352    13286.589844    13597.969727    13597.969727    5793430000  ^IXIC
2021-02-25  13512.639648    13602.860352    13066.379883    13119.429688    13119.429688    6335240000  ^IXIC
2021-02-26  13232.900391    13368.059570    13024.530273    13192.349609    13192.349609    5883880000  ^IXIC
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!